# access sqlite from .net standard 2.0

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-standard-2.0

I need to use .net standard 2.0 for my database component. This component uses the Microsoft package Microsoft.Data.Sqlite for access. That seems to work but how can I create a database file? Are there any other packages I may use for accessing Sqlite under a .net standard 2.0 component?

Best regards,
Torsten

Comment: Do you need to generate a sqllite file dynamically or just once?  A sqlite is a sdf file extension.  See : http://blog.tigrangasparian.com/2012/02/09/getting-started-with-sqlite-in-c-part-one/

Comment: I need to create it dynamicly. The CreateFile method does not exists in the package I use.

Comment: Then use the msdn library System.Data.SQLite for creating the file and not the library you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Following works:

```
using (var connection = new SqliteConnection("" + new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
{
     DataSource = "C:\\temp\\test.db"
}))
{
     connection.Open();

     using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
     {
           command.CommandText = "create table test(field1 varchar(20))";
           command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
 }
```

It is created by default, there is no explicit create file or anything like this.

Comment: depends on the package that's being used